# Use the definition of differentiation on a piecewise function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I need to find the derivative at $x=0$.

$$ f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x) & \text{if } x\neq 0 \\ 
0 & \text{if } x \leqslant 0 \end{cases} $$

Using the definition, I know that it's equal to $0$. However, I also need to prove that $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Do I need the entire equation for that?

Comment: You need to know what $f'$ is to prove it isn't continuous.

Comment: You need to know what $f'$ is in a small neighborhood around $x=0$ in order to prove it is continuous.  Continuity at a point depends on the behavior of the function around the point, so it is insufficient to only know the value of the function at the point.

Comment: If $x$ is chosen less than zero, which function are we taking for $y$ The first one or the second? I think instead of writing $x$ less or equal to zero, it should be $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $f'(0) = 0$. We have, then: $$f'(x) = \begin{cases} 2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x),& \text{if }x\neq 0 \\ 0, & \text{if } x \leq 0\end{cases}$$
Just check that $\lim_{x \to 0}f'(x)$ does not exist and you are done.